# QT Designer --- Designer.exe is Always crashing whenever I start it, the crash is also related to a call to QtCore4.dll , Any Suggestions?

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-creator

I am a newbie who is trying to use the QT creator, I installed the latest version "qt-win-opensource-4.5.1-mingw". Everything was working fine except for launching the QT Designer .. I don't really know what is the exact problem .. but whenever I try to edit my project visually or even to launch the QT Designer itself, the windows pops up an error message in which it mentions "designer.exe has stopped working".

I tried to debug with visual studio and the problem was in some steps for calling some DLL functions but I didnt really understand what was going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usualy worked for me

1. Uninstall QtCreator and other Qt versions.
2. Look for any Qt / Trolltech / Nokia keys in windows registry and remove them
3. Cleanup Qt directories
4. And then Install your IDE

Almost everytime i upgrade Qt Creator there are some problems with it if id don't remove older version.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late perhaps, but clearing the fileListBak and fileListOrg values under HKEY_CURRENT_USER -> SOFTWARE -> Trolltech -> Designer -> backup fixed it for me.

I believe the crash was caused by cutting power when the designer was open, causing the backing up to become corrupt somehow.

Answer (score -1):

This should be reported as a bug, not as a question on stackoverflow.

http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/

Comment: i have been trying to solve this issue for like 1 month .. and i already sent several inquiries for this error to their qt forums .. and even the official one ..